# Saving to DATE type column in SQL from C# - Linq to SQL

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, linq-to-sql

I'm having an issue with saving to a Date type column in SQL from Linq to SQL in C#

The issue being that I have a Date type column in SQL but when I pull this across into the dbml - The property swaps to DateTime.

Whenever I try and update this field via Linq to SQL the following error occurs:

> String or binary data would be truncated. The statement has been terminated.

Now I know this is due to the Type that Linq to SQL is trying to save being DateTime and the column itself being Date - But thus far I haven't found any solution to this.

What can I do to have Linq to SQL see the column type as Date opposed to DateTime when I pull the table in to the dbml - Or how can I save as DateTime to a Date type column.

Thanks

EDIT: Without submitting the entirety of the process simply the table is in the dbml and I'm selecting the row via the Id

Then I'm updating one of the fields (DateField) which has the Type of Date in SQL (Which has been pulled across in the dbml as DateTime as there's no Date type) and submitting the change.

```
var rowToUpdate = _db.Orders.First(o => o.Id == Id);

rowToUpdate.DateField = Convert.ToDateTime(txtNewDate.Text).Date;

_db.SubmitChanges();
```

Further to this, below shows the dbml (edited to show field name)

```
[global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.TableAttribute(Name="dbo.[Order]")]
public partial class Order : INotifyPropertyChanging, INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    [...]

    private int _Id;

    private System.Nullable<System.DateTime> _DateField;

    [...]
```

The DateTime property cannot be changed to Date (As far as I'm aware) and as such whenever I try and save to it, it's expecting a DateTime but causes an issue as it needs to truncate that to save as the expected Date type in SQL - throwing the error.

Comment: Can you edit your question and show the code that is giving you the error? You may just need to pass your date value as a string like: `dateVal.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");`

Comment: Are you really using linq-to-sql and not EF?  If so you might want to switch.

Comment: @dvo Updated to show the code to update the field.

Unfortunately it's how the rest of the project works so without changing multiple elements I can't, but I do see Entity Framework as being a benefit - Both have merits.

Additionally I did try the formatting of the DateTime to string - But I cannot implicitly change the type 'string' to 'DateTime' as it shows in the dbml - I could possibly change the dbml to have type of 'string' and see if that works, without changing the SQL table itself.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 var rowToUpdate = _db.Orders.First(o => o.Id == Id);

rowToUpdate.DateField = Convert.ToDateTime(txtNewDate.Text).Date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");

_db.SubmitChanges();
```

Comment: I have, unfortunately I get the error

Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'System.DateTime?'